# How do I make a ListView row draggable in .NET?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

I am not the most experienced GUI programmer, so bear with me here.  I have a custom list view.  I would like to be able to drag a row from the ListView to another control on a form.  I know how to catch events that are fired when an object is dragged to a control, but I am not sure how to make a row itself draggable.  I could always hack together my own solution, but I am hoping that there is a better (read: easier) way of doing this.

EDIT:  i would really like to drag a copy of the row, but I can always work out the details myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/skulkarni/ImlementingDragandDropinListViewControls11252005035642AM/ImlementingDragandDropinListViewControls.aspx